# String or binary data would be truncated from SQL Server to PostgreSQL linked server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I am trying to migrate some data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

There is a string column which causes an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

In SQL Server, my column type is `nvarchar(max)`, in PostgreSQL the type of the column is `text`.

My query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PGLINKED.MYPGDB.MYTARGETTABLE
    SELECT
        MyColumn
    FROM 
        MYSRCTABLE
```

However when I try cast MyColumn as nvarchar(4000) in select statement

```
INSERT INTO PGLINKED.MYPGDB.MYTARGETTABLE
    SELECT
        MyColumn = CAST(MyColumn AS NVARCHAR(4000))
    FROM 
        MYSRCTABLE
```

it works fine. But the string was truncated.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

`nvarchar(max)` is not the same as `nvarchar(4000)`. When you cast it to a lesser length, in this case from max down to 4000, you will truncate data.

Here is an example in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(100) = REPLICATE('A', 100)

SELECT @ AS uncasted, CAST(@ AS VARCHAR(4)) AS casted
```

Try casting it to `nvarchar(max)` on your insert.